# C++ Segmentation Fault in vector serialize/deserialize

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Please help me debug the below code. What I am doing is just serialize `vector<string>` into binary file and retrieving it back from it. Here is the example main code,

```
    /*  Portion Commented */
vector<string> list;

list.push_back("AAAAAA");
list.push_back("BBBBBB");
list.push_back("CCCCCC");
list.push_back("DDDDDD");

// Write out a list to a disk file
ofstream os ("/home/test/data.dat", ios::binary);

int size1 = list.size();
os.write((const char*)&size1, sizeof(int));
os.write((const char*)&list[0], size1 * sizeof(string));
os.close();
/* Portion Commented */

// Read it back in
VertexList list2;

ifstream is("/home/test/data.dat", ios::binary);
int size2;
is.read((char*)&size2, sizeof(int));

list2.resize(size2);
cout<<"Size is :"<<size2<<endl;
is.read((char*)&list2[0], size2 * sizeof(string));
for (int i=0; i < size2; i++)
{
        cout<<"At i = "<<i<<", "<<list2[i]<<endl;   //Line 40 in my program
}
```

I have 4 elements pushed into vector list. Then I serialize the vector and write it in a binary file and retrieving it back from same. It works fine.

Later when I comment the 'Portion Commented' in the above code and tried to retrieve the vector directly from the already created binary file "data.data", it shows segmentation fault event though it prints the size correctly as 4 just before the for loop. This is my valgrind output created with this (`valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out`),

```
==14058== Invalid read of size 8  
==14058==    at 0x4EBE263: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)  
==14058==    by 0x40107F: main (test2.cpp:40)  
==14058==  Address 0x2156010 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 40 is the `cout` statement in the last for loop. Can someone help me debug this ? Also tell me whether the above code is portable or not ?

thanks,
Prabu

Comment: `sizeof(string)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You forgot to actually *serialize* anything. You just wrote the contents of memory to disk without any concern for whether they could be re-interpreted to recover the *meaning* of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `std::string` includes a pointer to the actual string contents on the heap. So, `sizeof(string)` is just the pointer plus some bytes. If you want to write the string, you must write the contents itself

```
for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
    os.write(i->c_str(), i->size() + 1);
}
```

When you read that back in, you must look for the terminating NUL byte. Alternatively, you can save the length of the string, as you have done with the list

```
for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
    int len = i->size() + 1;
    os.write((const char*)&len, sizeof(len));
    os.write(i->c_str(), i->size() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But one question, it works exactly what i expect in the first case (i.e uncommenting the commented portion). In that case, for loop prints the contents exactly. Whereas when i tried to retrieve directly from data.dat file, it crashes in the for loop. What is the reason for this ?

Comment: ^The point is you have serialized the list instead of serializing the contents of the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
os.write((const char*)&list[0], size1 * sizeof(string));
```

What are you doing here? Casting `std::string` into `const char*`? That doesn't make sense.

If you use C++-style cast, the compiler will tell you why it doesn't make sense. That is why C++ programmers should avoid using C-style cast!

What you probably want to do is this:

```
os.write(list[0].c_str(), list[0].size() + 1);
```

And you should do that in a loop as:

```
for(auto const & s : list) //s is inferred to be std::string
{
  os.write(s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Always i did make mistake in using both C style and C++ style. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++, you should not save the structure or class for serialization, unless you know the implementation and there are no pointers in that.
The better way is to use boost serialization. They already did everything to support serialize/deserialize STL objects.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    vector<string> list1;

    list1.push_back("AAAAAA");
    list1.push_back("BBBBBB");
    list1.push_back("CCCCCC");
    list1.push_back("DDDDDD");

    // Write out a list to a disk file
    ofstream os ("data.dat", ios::binary);

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);
    oa << list1;
    os.close();

    vector<string> list2;

    ifstream is("data.dat", ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> list2;
    int size2 = list2.size();
    for (int i=0; i < size2; i++)
    {
       cout<<"At i = "<<i<<", "<<list2[i]<<endl;   //Line 40 in my program
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know this option in boost. But in our product so far we haven't used this Boost Library. So only I tried to avoid the same. Any how in future, we will try to integrate this in our product.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof( std::string )` gives you size of the `string` object. Actual string data itself is dynamic and held by a pointer in `string` class.

You might want to use [google protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [boost serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for serialize/de-serialize objects.